# How to get 2048 x 2048 Images in Google Streeview API

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone have any idea how to get google streetview images beyond the standard 640x640. The basic code is pretty straightforward, but not for the images. When I run the code below, I get empty .jpgs

```
def GetStreetPrem(address, filename):
address = unidecode.unidecode(address.strip())
base = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=2048x2048&fov=70" + google_key + google_signature + "&location="
print(base)
repr(address)
print(address)
print(filename)
urllib.urlretrieve(base + address, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Imagesizes) you need the Google Maps API Premium Plan to get that size images:

> maximum allowable values for the size parameter 
>   API                           scale=1   
>   Google Maps APIs Premium Plan 2048x2048